# Flask not serving image

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I have a form where users upload a file and its path is stored in a database and the file is stored in `'/static/uploads/images/'`.

Now in my templates when I call for that image to be displayed I am doing this: `<img src="{{ asset_info.picture_location }}" />`

The `picture_location` is the column where the path is being kept.  The `asset_info` is the model object.

For some reason it is returning a 404 when attempting to retrieve the image:
`GET /static/uploads/images/motor.gif HTTP/1.1" 404 -`even though that is the correct path and I can see the file in there.

Inspecting the url of the broken image icon on the page shows it is retrieving the correct path from the database: `http://localhost:5000/static/uploads/images/motor.gif`

The response on the client brower says this:

`The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.`

I've googled around quite a bit but have not had any luck.  Is there a separate method I'm supposed to call / build to serve images?

This blueprints info: `assets_blueprint = Blueprint('assets', __name__, static_folder='/static', template_folder='templates')`

Directory is:

```
app/
    assets/
        views.py
        asset_models.py
        asset_forms.py

    other_blueprints/
        etc.py

    static/
        uploads/
            images/
                motor.gif

app.py
config.py
```

Comment: where is your statuc folder?

Comment: @realli Updated main post with directory layouts and static folder info.

Comment: @realli Actually I figured out the problem, I just don't know how to fix it.

Because this is all happening within the assets blueprint, and `/assets/` sub-route `(@assets_blueprint.route('/assets/<string:asset_tag>')` it is for some reason appending `/assets/` in front of the path to the image, like so;
`/assets/static/uploads/images/motor.gif`
But the path it is retrieving from the database is just:
`/static/uploads/images/motor.gif`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I had manual settings in the blueprint overriding the default root static folder.  I took those out and it defaulted back to serving from the default root static folder, then updated my template code to:

`<img src="{{ url_for('static', filename=asset_info.picture_location) }}" />` telling it to retrieve the path from the static root folder.  I also then had to append my database location formatting by removing the `/static/` from the string concatenation because the `url_for('static' ....` includes that when it generates the url:

Old:
`filename_input = str('static/uploads/images/' + str(request.files['photo'].filename))`
New:
`filename_input = str('uploads/images/' + str(request.files['photo'].filename))`